# Facebook Like Button API - Like different URL to page button is on?

Tags: facebook, api, url

I have a large image gallery web page. I want to have a Facebook 'Like' button per image, so I set the API URL for each like button to be something like:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://mysite.com/gallery/photo1.jpg" data-send="true" data-width="300" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

However, the Facebook API seems to not like this. The console says there is a mismatch between domains.

I am assuming this is because the actual 'Like' button is on one URL, eg: `mysite.com/gallery` whilst the URL it is told to like is diffent, eg: `mysite.com/gallery/photo1.jpg` as once I set them both to the same URL it is fine.

Does anyone know of a work around for this? Have a Facebook Like button on one page, but the page to like on another, separate page?

Comment: are the two links actually on the same domain?

Comment: are you sure that the like wasn't registered?

Comment: Yes - every seems to work fine: I click the like, login to FB if need be, write up some text about the page and hit submit. It just doesnt appear on anyones actual FB timeline

Comment: did you test here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: @GilBirman Thanks - but no luck for me there

Comment: @GilBirman I get 'Can't Download:Could not retrieve data from URL.' Perhaps this a permissions issue? I will check those

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitively add a like button for a content on another domain.

For the moment, there's a bug on Facebook Like buttons' callbacks, and likes are often not taken into account.

The issue should be solved soon : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/457950334238629

Comment: OK so I narrowed down the issue. You are right in that it does work between two different URLs. The issue I have found is that it will not work on liking images files (or the url pointing to an image file). This has differed from my original question so I will start a question. Thanks

Comment: I think it works also with images.Try it by yourself :  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
Enter you image url, and when the like button is refreshed on the right just click on it. It should work.

Comment: By the way, this like on an image will not appear anywhere (not in your graph, and friends probably won't see it). A better practice would be to like a unique page containing Open Graph tags that contains your image.

Comment: Ah right - yeah It seemed to be working fine - FB login box appeared etc, the like just didnt appear on anyones timeline

Answer (score 1):

Get the link you want to like working in the Facebook debugger and it should work:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

*Update*: I don't know if the question changed or I was just zoned out, but you cannot *like* a **JPG** file.